# How to get n items max by properties and sort in JSON

Tags: json

I have an JSON object structured like this:

```
{A : 1, B : 5, C : 1, D : 3, E: 4, F: 4, G: 2}
```

I would like a function that can get 5 items has max properties and I don't know how to do it. I would need an output like this:

```
{B: 5, E: 4, F: 4, D : 3, G : 2}
```

Is there any way that I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: JSON is a data type, not a programming language. There's no "functions" in JSON. I'm assuming you mean in Javascript? But many many other languages use JSON, so please specify.